# Semaphores wait() on Multicore

Tags: mutex, semaphore, multicore, mutual-exclusion, busy-waiting

I'm currently studying how semaphores and mutual exclusion actually work and encountered the following problem.

Let's assume we have two cores on a CPU. We have two processes, on each core there's running one. We're now calling on both cores a wait() call, because we wish to enter a critical section:

```
wait(){
  while(s.value <= 0)
    // busy waiting
  s.value--;
}
```

If both cores execute the code in parallel, and the initial semaphore value is 1, both read the while loop statement, which results to `false` (since the `s = 1`). That means, both decrement the semaphore nearly at the same time, which results to `s = -1`. Now, both processes enter their critical section at the same time, and that shouldn't be possible in terms of mutual exclusion.

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks for clarification.

Comment: The wait for non-zero count and decrement are usually handled within the kernel of an operating system, in a manner that makes the check and decrement an atomic operation.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already discovered, these are not simple user-space functions - it will be very tricky (impossible?) for you to implement a semaphore or mutex yourself without using the functions provided by the kernel.

For example, on Linux you have:

- [`sem_wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait) / [`sem_post()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post)
- [`pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)

---

You have the concept correct but the two operations (the check and the inc/dec) need to be conducted in an "*atomic*" way - simplistically this means that they happen as one operation that cannot be split (read up on [Linearizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability)).

Additionally, it's worth noting that you have implemented a 'busy loop', which when working with an operating system is a *bad idea* as you are depriving other tasks / processes from CPU time and raising the power usage while doing no actual work - the functions mentioned above will "*block*" with 0% CPU usage, while yours will "*block*" with 100% CPU usage if given the chance.

---

You would have more luck trying to 'play' with such concepts when running on a single core (you can restrict your applications execution to a single core - look at [sched_setaffinity()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity).

However, even if you get that going you have very little control over whether your process is scheduled out at a bad time causing your example application to break in exactly the same way. It might be possible to further improve your chances of correct operation by calling `sched_setscheduler()` with `SCHED_FIFO`, though I've not got first hand experience with this ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595897/1347519), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2865870/1347519)).

Either way, this is not likely to be 100% reliable, while the kernel-supported functions should be.

---

If you're up for it, then the best way to play with the implementation details in your own functions would be to implement a very basic round-robin scheduler (that doesn't interrupt tasks) and run it on a micro or in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

in java and in other languages you ca use synchronized to synchronize a block of code or a function and that avoid this kind of problemes because When one thread is executing a synchronized method or a block , all other threads that invoke synchronized methods or blocks  (suspend execution) until the first thread is done.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to use the built-in functions for the semaphore. To wait using the pthreads library, you'd use the `pend()` function, and to make the semaphore available, you'd use the `post()` function.

`pend` will wait until the value of `s` is greater than 0. Then it will atomically decrement the value of `s` and then continue onward. How this is exactly implemented depends on the library, of course. It may look something like this:

```
sem_wait(){
    // Make a kernel function call to guarantee that the following code is atomic
    enter_critical_section();
    // Test the semaphore value. If it is positive, let the code continue.
    int sem_val = s.value;
    s.value--;
    if (sem_val > 0) {
        exit_critical_section();
        return;
    }
    else {
    // At this point we know the semaphore value is negative, so it's not available. We'd want to block the caller and make a context switch to a different thread or task.
    ... // Put the current thread on list of blocked threads
    ... // Make a context switch to a ready thread.
    }
    // When the semaphore is made available with a sem_post() function call somewhere else, there will eventually be a context switch back to this (blocked) thread. Simply exit the critical section, return back to the calling function, and let the program execute normally.
    exit_critical_section();
}
```

This code is actually based off an RTOS I implemented for a class. Each implementation will look very different, and there's a lot I haven't shown here, but it should give you a basic idea of how it could work.

Finally, you mentioned in your hypothetical case that there were 2 separate processes sharing a single semaphore. That's possible, you just have to make certain to make the right function calls to make the semaphore shareable between processes.